# In Menu Bar Select particular Element

Tags: java, selenium

```
package com.s3sales.demo;

import java.awt.AWTException;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;


public class Settings_Area {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, AWTException {

        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("http://sssamriddhisales.com/crm");

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        driver.findElement(By.id("userName")).sendKeys("admin");

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("admin123");     

        Thread.sleep(2000); 

        driver.findElement(By.className("btn-success")).click();

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Settings")); 

        WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 3);

         JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;

          js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,100)");

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));

         Thread.sleep(1000);

         Actions action = new Actions(driver);

         action.moveToElement(element).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-id='area']"))).click().build().perform();

         Thread.sleep(1000);







    }

}
```

In Menu bar , I have a list of elements in that scroll down bar not moving .But, i want to select particular element is Area(Settings) .I have tried my below code . But, showing as Exception in thread “main” java.lang.ClassCastException ..Please me code[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbdEo.png)

Comment: can you show us some html for that element with list?

Comment: Can you mention on which line you are getting the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
driver.get("http://sssamriddhisales.com/crm");

        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES).pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class, ElementNotVisibleException.class);
        WebElement userName = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return driver.findElement(By.id("userName"));
            }
        });
        WebElement password = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
            }
        });
        WebElement submit = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']"));
            }
        });

        userName.sendKeys("admin");
        password.sendKeys("admin123");     
        submit.click();

        WebElement settings = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='text-center']//span[text()='Settings']"));
            }
        });
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.moveToElement(settings).build().perform();

        final WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-id='area']//a[text()='Area']"));
        WebElement area = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return element;
            }
        });
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
        area.click();
```

Using Thread.sleep() is not a good idea so I have removed it and replaced with FluentWait. You can change it if you want to.

The above code will login to the application, then do mouse over on the settings then clicks the Area.

Comment: Can you explain code step by step(Sorry for asking)

Comment: No problem, I'm performing the same steps as you are doing but I have changed the way of locating the web elements a bit and have removed Thread.sleep().

Comment: Until login into the application, your code will work I guess. After that, no need to click on the 'Settings' as it is displaying the list by doing the mouse over itself so I have used to 'Actions' class to move the control to there and after that using the 'JavascriptExecutor', getting that element view then clicking on it.

Comment: If the FluentWait doesn't work then you use Thread.sleep() only.

Comment: code working .Thank you Brother ,I have seen all the class and methods explanation in Internet ..(If you are OK)can you give your id like Facebook ,LinkedIn ,Instagram for any help...and Once Again thank you for Helping in code..

Comment: You are welcome... Search `alicse3` in Google and that is my LinkedIn, Instagram handle

Comment: Sure Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try below code:

```
    driver.get("http://sssamriddhisales.com/crm");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("userName")).sendKeys("admin");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("admin123");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.className("btn-success")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='text-center']//span[text()='Settings']"));
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(element).perform();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-id='area']//a[text()='Area']")).click();
```

Comment: Sorry Bro, its Not Working

Comment: Hi @Bhavesh Soni, that is not what he wants to do. He wants to Select some options from left side after mouse hovering on Settings. Not in right side top corner admin settings...

Comment: ohh I am sorry , i did not checked it properly. updated the code for the same.